# Meteor loop two template helpers to fill up table

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-blaze

I have to fill a table with the headers as seen from this [image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFUTQ.png)

However, the data corresponding to those headers are scattered through two (possibly three) different collections. Is it possible to loop through those collections at the same time to fill up the table? I am a total newbie in Meteor (less than one week experience) and MonogoDB so any inputs will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll want to use a template helper to consolidate the data into one array.

Comment: @Gaelan can you walk me through how I can do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can get us the basic content of the collection, we could possibly help. This seems to be more from a mongo query  / JS than anything to do with meteor as such.

Comment: @blueren I don't know how to put the mongo queries here, but let's say the first four table heads can be fetched from collection1, and the remaining for collection two. Hope that helps.